# In PowerShell - How do I create parent and children OU's at the same time?

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I am using a Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am the administrator. My PowerShell Version is 4.0. My domain is DC=testdomene,DC=local.

I want to accomplish the following:
1) Create a parent OU
2) Create some children OU's at the same time

I am able to do this manually in PowerShell, but I guess one of the major benefits of using PowerShell is to automate this somehow. The "Help New-ADOrganizationalUnit -examples" do not give me any answers when it comes to parent and children OU's at the same time.

Creating the parent OU:
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "US" -Path "DC=testdomene,DC=local" -description Parent -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false

Creating the first child OU:
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Nevada" -Path "OU=US,DC=testdomene,DC=local" -description Child -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false

Creating the second child OU:
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Texas" -Path "OU=US,DC=testdomene,DC=local" -description Child -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false

This gives me the OU US, with the children OU's Nevada and Texas. How would I accomplish this at the same time? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ta da! :) Yes, there is a way to do this. I am not going to take credit for the solution, because I had a lot of help from a friend of mine. He doesn't really like being mentioned on the internet, so for now, I will leave his name out of it.

I used country, states and cities as a demonstration, but the main purpose is off course to make an organization, with departments and sub departments all in one script and without any input when the script runs. First I will paste the textfile and then the script that makes it all work. Some names are in Norwegian, but where it is neccessary I will translate the meaning.

**Textfile(1) demonstration as follows: The name of the textfile is OUStructure.txt**

```
US
US/Florida
US/Florida/Miami
US/Texas
US/Texas/Houston
US/Texas/Dallas
US/Nevada
US/Nevada/Las Vegas
US/Nevada/By1
US/Nevada/By2
US/Nevada/By2/Computers
US/Colorado
US/Colorado/Austin
```

Short Explanation: By1 and By2 is Norwegian for town1 and town2. Computers has nothing to do with cities. I just wanted to see if I could make even more sub OU's underneath the sub.

**Textfile(2) demonstration as follows: The name of the textfile is OUStructure.txt. I guess this is what I was looking for when I was asking my question.**

```
TechCorp
TechCorp\Production
TechCorp\Management
TechCorp\Sales
TechCorp\IT
```

**Scriptfile as follows. The name of the scriptfile is import_OU_Fra_Fil.ps1**

```
Get-Content OUStructure.txt | Foreach-Object {
  $domene = 'DC=testdomene,DC=local'
  $alleOU = ''
  $ous = (Split-Path $_ -Parent).Split('\')
  [array]::Reverse($ous)
  $ous | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Length -eq 0) {
      return
    }
    $alleOU = $alleOU + 'OU=' + $_ + ','
  }
  $alleOU += $domene
  $nyOUNavn = Split-Path $_ -Leaf

  New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "$nyOUNavn" -Path "$alleOU" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
}
```

Explanation:

Fra_Fil which is part of the scriptfile name is Norwegian for From_File.

DC=testdomene,DC=local is my own domain.

alleOU is Norwegian for AllOU, meaning all of the OU's.

nyOUNavn is Norwegian for NewOUName.

This worked for me, and I hope it can help anyone out there looking for the same solution. I am just starting out using StackOverflow so if anyone feels the need to edit my post to make it clearer, please do so. I put the textfile information in code quotes, because I couldn't figure out how to seperate the lines. Personally I learned a lot from this. My problem is that I am googling for solutions when I should have been googling for the purpose of split and reverse arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for recursive creation in the ActiveDirectory module or Quest ActiveRoles AD Snapin. You will have to do it manually.

You could write your own function that checks if the parent out exists or use a trap or try/catch to catch the error, and then create the parent ou automatically.

Answer (score 1):

NEW-ADOrganizationalUnit “Nevada” –path “OU=Texas,OU=US,DC=testdomene,DC=local”

Just use OU twice and it will nest.

Answer (score 0):

```
# change value of domain mane to your domain
$MyDomain = "dc=myRMS,dc=local"

#Connect to your domain container
$connectionString = "LDAP://" + $MyDomain
$objDomain  = [ADSI]$connectionString

Get-Content OUStructure1.txt | Foreach-Object {
  $domain = 'DC=myRMS,DC=local'
  $newOU = ''
  $ous = (Split-Path $_ -Parent).Split('\')
  [array]::Reverse($ous)
  $ous | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Length -eq 0) {
      return
    }
    $newOU = $newOU + ',OU=' + $_
  }
  #$newOU += $domain

  $nyOUNavn = Split-Path $_ -Leaf
  $newOU = 'OU=' + $nyOUNavn + $newOU

  #Create new Organizational Unit
  $objOU = $objDomain.Create("organizationalUnit", "$newOU")
  $objOU.SetInfo()
}
```

This is different version of code proposed above. I used LDAP connection.